# 'Show Icons' option missing from Productivity Power Tools 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, productivity-power-tools

I'm running VS 2013 and have the Productivity Power Tools extension installed, but I'm not seeing this option listed. According to what I've read, I should be able to see it under **Options** → **Productivity Power Tools** → **Custom Document Well** → **General** but it isn't showing up for me?

This is what I'm expecting to see (per http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kalisk/11-productivity-features-for-developers-in-visual-studio-201/):
[image: Options window shows the "Show Icons" option listed under the Tab Appearance section]

And this is what I'm actually seeing:
[image: The option for "Show Icons" is missing]

**Update**:
Since there hasn't been a lot of feedback on this, could I at least get some simple confirmations (or denials) that this option is even available to any of you that have this setup (PPT2013 installed with VS2013)? I don't even know if this is an actual feature that I *should* be seeing.

Comment: Same here. Any help?

Comment: Same here. I'm loosing my mind. Not being able to tell whether a tab is .h or .cpp before I open it is a waste of time.